# Possible to convert style object with pseudo classes for use in styled-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components

I’m working on refactoring a large component-library that uses Tailwind + Emotion, replacing both with styled-components. There is a utility method in place that returns one or more style objects that look like this:

```js
{
    "backgroundColor": "var(--sb-colors-primary-20, #F0F2F4)",
    ":focus-within": {
        "backgroundColor": "var(--sb-colors-primary-20, #F0F2F4)",
        "borderWidth": "1px",
        "borderColor": "var(--sb-colors-primary-50, #ADB5BD)"
    },
    ":hover": {
        "backgroundColor": "var(--sb-colors-primary-30, #DEE2E6)"
    }
}
```

This utility is going to be around for a bit, until all components that use it are refactored. Then it can be addressed.

So, knowing that, is there any way to convert an object (or array of objects) like this to something styled-components can consume and respect the pseudo classes? I would be passing it into the styled-component as a transient prop.

Answer (score 0):

As for now, you can just pass those styles as inline styles prop into your new components, I'm thinking on something like:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import styled from "styled-components";

function myUtilityFunction() {
  return {
    backgroundColor: "var(--sb-colors-primary-20, #F0F2F4)",
    ":focus-within": {
      backgroundColor: "var(--sb-colors-primary-20, #F0F2F4)",
      borderWidth: "1px",
      borderColor: "var(--sb-colors-primary-50, #ADB5BD)"
    },
    ":hover": {
      backgroundColor: "var(--sb-colors-primary-30, #DEE2E6)"
    }
  };
}

const MyStyledComponent = styled.div`
  ${(props) => props.styles}
`;

export default function App() {
  return <MyStyledComponent styles={myUtilityFunction()}>Hello</MyStyledComponent>;
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

```css
:root {
  --sb-colors-primary-20: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/6.0.7/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```